# UIScreen substitute for MacOS software

Tags: swiftui, screen-size

I was using the following to get the screen size of `iOS` devices. How to get similar in `macOS` apps?

```
extension UIScreen{
    static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}
```

1. Is there any way to get the software width and height
2. Is there any way to get the screen (monitor/laptop screen) width and height

Comment: Replace `UI` with `NS` and `bounds` with `frame`. By the way `CGRect` can get `width` and `height` directly.

Comment: It throws errors when I try `static let screenWidth = NSScreen.main.frame.size.width`Reference to member 'size' cannot be resolved without a contextual type` Referencing instance method 'frame(width:height:alignment:)' on 'Optional' requires that 'NSScreen' conform to 'View'`

Comment: @vadian: Can you pls post an answer? I want to use it as an extension. I will update my question as well.

Comment: `main` is optional in macOS. Optional bind it or force unwrap it if there is always at least one connected screen. And please show the environment where it’s called. And as already mentioned `size` is not needed (not even in iOS).

Comment: @vadian it's very unclear of what you're saying. Are you saying this `NSScreen.fram.width`, then it throws error `Cannot use instance member 'frame' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`  It's inside an extension, I have updated the code above. If you just post an answer with the code below, than commenting here, it'll be more clear.